# How to hot deploy maven project to glassfish?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven, glassfish

I have a webapp project generated with **m2e** maven plugin in *eclipse indigo*. And i have a *embedded glassfish* plugin configured in my *pom.xml*. Right now when i change something i have to `mvn clean package`, `mvn embedded-glassfish:run`, see whats up, then press x in console and server shutdowns. Is there any way to make things easier? Ny help would be appreceited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try Oracle Enterprise Pack (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html) which has support for Glassfish (using WebTools infrastructure so it can work with m2e-wtp).